# Roman numerals in treetop grammar

Tags: ruby, treetop

I want to parse an ordered list, which is something like:

```
I - Something
II - Something else...
IX - Something weird
XIII - etc
```

So far, my treetop grammar is:

```
rule text
    roman_numeral separator text newline
end

rule roman_numeral
    &. ('MMM' / 'MM' / 'M')? (('C' [DM]) / 
    ('D'? ('CCC' / 'CC' / 'C')?))? (('X' [LC]) / 
    ('L'? ('XXX' / 'XX' / 'X')?))? (('I' [VX]) / 
    ('V'? ('III' / 'II' / 'I')?))?
end

rule separator
    [\s] "-" [\s]
end

rule text
    (!"\n" .)*
end

rule newline
    ["\n"]
end
```

However, the corresponding parser is unable to parse the text. What is broken?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You accidentally overloaded `text`. Rename the first to `line`, and then add another rule for `lines`.

The quotes around newline also seem unnecessary.

Side tip - you can reuse the `newline` rule in your `text` rule to keep it DRY.

```
grammar Roman

  rule lines
    line*
  end

  rule line
    roman_numeral separator text newline
  end

  rule roman_numeral
    &. ('MMM' / 'MM' / 'M')? (('C' [DM]) /
    ('D'? ('CCC' / 'CC' / 'C')?))? (('X' [LC]) /
    ('L'? ('XXX' / 'XX' / 'X')?))? (('I' [VX]) /
    ('V'? ('III' / 'II' / 'I')?))?
  end

  rule separator
    [\s] "-" [\s]
  end

  rule text
    (!newline .)*
  end

  rule newline
    [\n]
  end

end
```

#### Update

You can simplify the grammar a little bit by removing the negative lookahead and the single character classes.

```
rule separator
  " - "
end

rule text
  [^\n]*
end
```

The resulting syntax graph becomes much simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was precisely what I needed to know. I also made the refactorings you suggested making my grammar a bit more clear and concise. Thanks.